# Searching for specific member of List in c#

Tags: c#, linq, xna

I have three classes (Street, Shop , StartingPoint) inherited from class Event. 
I created List`List<Event> eventList = new List<Event>();` and added them in List : `eventList.Add(new Street());` `eventList.Add(new Shop());`etc.
How can i acces specific class ? For example i want  working only with Shop. How can i acces it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With indexer ?

```
eventList[index]
```

Or `LINQ` ?

```
eventList.OfType<Shop>().First();
```

[`OfType<Shop>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will return all `Shops`.If you want single `Shop` you can use `First.`

Comment: okay i will try it. And if i have something like this : `Street street1 = new Street();` and then `eventList.Add(street1);` how can i acces street1 ? You know im pretty new in this. Thanks much for answer

Comment: you need  something to identify `street1`.you can't access it by instance name. Instead you can use dictionary, `Dictionary<string,Event>` maybe.Or you can access it with some `properties.eventList.Where( event => event.Name == "something");`

Answer (score 0):

Like Selman22 said you can use `eventList.OfType<Shop>().First();` to access on the first shop in your list. If you want to have a specified shop you have to work with the name of the shop or the street or whatever.

This will then look like;

```
eventList.OfType<Shop>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.StreetName == "WallStreet");
```

That returns you the Shop where the streetname of the Shop is like "WallStreet"